# Reload SQL Query with AJAX/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im very confused on how I can use AJAX can reload a portion of a webpage that uses PHP to execute an SQL query on my database. Here is my example

```
 <tbody>
      <?php 

         $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM script_data WHERE email = :email OR username = :uname");
         $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$_SESSION['username'], ':email' => $_SESSION['email']));    
         $count = $stmt->rowCount();

         while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['script_ID'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . gmdate("H:i:s", $row['runtime']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['script_name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['script_version'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';  

                   }

                  if($count == 0) {
                    $bot_is_running = false;
                     echo '<tr>';
                     echo '<td>No active Bots</td>';
                     echo '</tr>';
                        }

                       ?>
     </tbody>
```

This is simply getting information from a database and presenting it as a table my problem is that it needs to be refreshed every 5 seconds or so for the most up to date data (my database is constantly being updated with new data from a java application)

any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: jQuery has a `.load()` function which might be of use to you: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: JS has a `setInterval()` function you can use with the function @David mentions above in order to created a timed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this page content is on a page which can be requested in some way?  Let's call it `myPage.php` for the sake of example.  You can use [the `.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in jQuery to fetch a page from the server and place its content in an element.  For example:

```
$('tbody').load('myPage.php tbody tr');
```

This would replace the contents of `tbody` in the current page with the `tr` elements returned from the requested page.

In order to do that "every 5 seconds" you'd use something like `setInterval()`.  For example:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('tbody').load('myPage.php tbody tr');
}, 5000);
```

Note: Fetching page contents from the server isn't the fastest way to do things, so if you're going to be re-loading this *a lot* (every few seconds) then you might speed things up a bit.  Create a separate PHP page which just returns the updated *data* instead of an entirely rendered page.  Then instead of `.load()`, use a `.get()` to fetch the JSON data from that page and update the client-side markup you already have.

There are *many* ways to go about doing that, depending on what technologies you're using.  Fetching the whole page should *work*, but I recommend you look into a more structured way of doing this even just as a learning experience.

Comment: Yes this is just what I needed im going to put it into practice and see if it works!